# Center react modal vertically and horizontally on selected div - not on window

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I am using [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal). It works fine and ends up centered vertically and horizontally referenced to the window.

I have menus top and left and the rest is a workspace / canvas. I would like the modal to center (both x & y direction) using this area as reference.

Can this be done easily?

I have tried to change it like this

```
Modal.setAppElement('#canvas');
```

still centering to window.